# Error while executing java code in batch script

Tags: java, windows, batch-file

Here is my batch script to execute a java code-

```
@echo off
@setlocal

set JARS=log4j.jar;commons-logging-1.0.4.jar
set abc="JAVA_HOME\bin\java" -cp %JARS%; "C:\Documents and settings\Administrator\Desktop\Temp" Test

echo %abc%

%abc%
```

And i get this error-

```
The system cannot find the path specified.
```

I have copied the compiled class file in the same location. But to be on a safer side i've provided the path of the class file above. Am I going wrong somewhere?

Comment: you still don't have your -cp set correctly, see my answer.  the -cp argument is _one string enclosed in quotes_ and _no spaces after the ";"_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me

```
@echo off   
set JAVA_HOME="C:\Program Files\java\jre6"
set JARS=".;C:\Program Files\lib\log4j.jar;C:\Program Files\lib\commons-logging-1.1.1.jar;"
set runJava=%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java -cp %JARS% Test
%runJava%
```

Answer (score 1):

sorry, dont have much time, but dont you want the output of JAVA_HOME?

for that you would use % like:

```
set x="%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java"
```

Comment: The outcome is still the same.

Answer (score 0):

for starters you need:

```
set cmd="%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java" -cp "log4j.jar;commons-logging-1.0.4.jar;C:\Documents and settings\Administrator\Desktop\Temp" Test
```

update:

showed how classname "Test" should be incorporated.

Comment: actually "Test" is the classname.Should i append it with " .class"?

Comment: @hari Yes append it with a .class

Comment: @hari See my admended answer below

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
@setlocal

set command="%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java" -cp log4j.jar;commons-logging-1.0.4.jar;"C:\Documents and settings\Administrator\Desktop\Temp" Test

echo %command%

%command%
```

1. `cmd` is a reserved word, you can't use it as a variable like
   that!
2. System variables should be `%`'d to be substituted.
3. Use double quotes for paths containing spaces.
4. You can't give the path to a class to run a class. You have to just
   give the class name.

Comment: In addition, most Java newcomers set the value of `JAVA_HOME` all the way till inside the `bin` directory. **DO NOT** do that.

Comment: @hari Can you show the output of `%JAVA_HOME%`and `%command%`? What do you mean not working? Does it still say `The system cannot find the path specified.`?

Comment: @hari I never asked you to put `Test.class` there! That **WON'T** work!

Comment: Also, where is `%JAVA_HOME%` being used? I don't see it being replaced at all!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3297/discussion-between-hari-and-adarshr)

Answer (score -1):

This is an amalgamtaion of the above answers. All are correct is part.

```
@echo off

set runJava="%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java" -cp log4j.jar;commons-logging-1.0.4.jar "C:\Documents and settings\Administrator\Desktop\Temp\Test.class"

echo %runJava%

%runJava%
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the outcome is still the same.

Comment: I have made a significant edit to the answer. Ignore the above comment.

Comment: Tried what you suggested. I'm getting the same message!!I seriously don't know where I'm going wrong.

Comment: I use the following for running jars "%_JAVACMD%" %RUNTIME_OPTS% -Djava.ext.dirs=%EXT_DIRS% -jar dist\some.jar %*% where EXT_DIRS contain a list of all required jars. Something like it might work for running a class